# Prevent inbound external traffic to specific page and redirect

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I have searched and found solutions that were close, but I have not found anything that is exactly what I'm looking for. I have a two page/step form. I would like all external traffic pointing to page two to be redirected to page one of the form. However, traffic from page one needs to get to page two without being redirected back to page one.

Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @pintxo apache redirect based on referrer seems like a great idea... how ever I can not account for all referring sites. I haven't seen a good example of preventing all referrers except for my site. The closest example I've seen is trying to modify a image hot link prevention like this -> http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/access.html

Comment: Well, as I understood your problem there is one valid referrer and all others should be redirected. So simply negate the RewriteCond? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824964/rewritecond-in-htaccess-with-negated-regex-condition-doesnt-work for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^form/page2.php$ http://example..com/form/page1.php [L,R]
```

Going to `http://example.com/form/page2.php` will redirect you to `http://example.com/form/page1.php` unless you are linked to `page2.php` from within `site.com`.